# NPE reading a spark Spark Dataset

Tags: apache-spark, dataset

I have an RDD that I grouped based on the size of the rows (each row has a different size) in a `foreachPartition`. then for each of these groups (a list of Strings), I am creating a new Dataset, so I can write them to storage. basically I am trying to split the RDD by size and update the target (controlled by size). Spark's new `maxRecordsPerFile` won't work for me because each row has a blob that will make the row sizes different. So here is my code, I am getting null pointer exception reading the newly created dataset:

Caller:

```java
JavaRDD<String> stringRDD = xmlDataSet.toJavaRDD().map(xmlRow -> extractXMLBlobToJsonString(xmlRow)).rdd().toJavaRDD();
    GroupBySizeManager mgr = GroupBySizeManager.getInstance();
    jsonRDD.foreachPartition(mgr::splitPartition);
```

Function `splitPartition` in `GroupBySizeManager.java`

```java
public void splitPartition(Iterator<String> rowsInPartition) {
    System.out.println("********Number of groups " + this.getGroups().size());
    SparkSession sparkSession = SparkDataflowConfig.getInstance().getSparkSession();
    while (rowsInPartition.hasNext()) {
        addToGroup(rowsInPartition.next());         
    }
        
    for(List<String> rows: getRows()) {
        System.out.println("******Size of List: " + rows.size());
        Dataset<String> dataset = sparkSession.createDataset(rows, Encoders.STRING());
        Dataset<Row> xmldf = sparkSession.read().json(dataset);// NPE here
         System.out.println("Count of xmlfiltered: " + xmldf.count());
         xmldf.write().format("csv").option("header", "true").save("/home/myfilepath/");             
    }
}
```

Receiving the following NPE on the above `sparkSession.read().json(dataset)`. This same code works if I just do it on my initial RDD before I did this grouping and recreating Dataset

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.sparkContext(SparkPlan.scala:67)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeQuery(SparkPlan.scala:215)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.execute(SparkPlan.scala:176)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.toRdd$lzycompute(QueryExecution.scala:132)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.toRdd(QueryExecution.scala:131)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.json.TextInputJsonDataSource$.inferFromDataset(JsonDataSource.scala:104)
at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.$anonfun$json$1(DataFrameReader.scala:567)
at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:189)
at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.json(DataFrameReader.scala:567)
at com.bm.xchange.spark.executor.GroupBySizeManager.splitPartition(GroupBySizeManager.java:57)
at org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaRDDLike.$anonfun$foreachPartition$1(JavaRDDLike.scala:219)
at org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaRDDLike.$anonfun$foreachPartition$1$adapted(JavaRDDLike.scala:219)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.$anonfun$foreachPartition$2(RDD.scala:1020)
```

I have been reading more and I think I know why I am seeing the exception. It seems like we cannot create a dataset in the executor, but only in the driver. So this logic of mine wont work. Is there any better way to do this (split partition based on file size) without causing shuffle or repartition?
Appreciate your help
thank you

Comment: Thanks for asking your question! The idea here on Stackoverflow is that for each question post, we ask only 1 question. The reasons why are discussed [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/39223/one-post-with-multiple-questions-or-multiple-posts) for example. Could you edit your post to only ask a single question please? Thanks!

Comment: I edited it to ask only one question. thank you.

Comment: Ahh awesome, thanks! I see that you say "This same code works if I just do it on my initial RDD before I did this grouping and recreating Dataset". Could you show us the code that works? That will help out pinpointing the problem :)

Comment: Hi Koedlt, its the same above code. I just meant this code runs (does not mean it worked), in driver, but throws exception in the executor). The reason was that createDataSet can only be done on the driver. Executor cannot run parallelize operations